# how to integrating mixare augmented reality sdk into our own android app

Tags: android, augmented-reality

```
    how to integrate mixare ar sdk into our own apps ,my apps using google places api and getting nearby places according to location type abd how to pass google places api web service to mixare sdk ..
```

is there any another way getting nearby places by using mixare ar sdk

```
thanks
```

Answer (score 4):

You also can try an other framework for the augmented reality, like [BeyondAR](https://github.com/BeyondAR/beyondar). This one is Apache v2 license :)

Answer (score 3):

Mixare supports the integration of your own data, as explained on this webpage: [Display Your Own Data](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/DisplayYourOwnData)

The supported format is JSON. the Google Places API also supports JSON but don't use exactly the same syntax for search results (e.g. nearby POI) as for Mixare.

So what you can do:

- Solution 1: retrieve independently your POI with the Google API using your existing code, reformat the JSON Google Places result to be compatible with the JSON Mixare format and add the content as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/UseCasesExplanation) via some `i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content:// ")` function call.
- Solution 2: extend Mixare with a derived Data Processor class handling request from Google Places API. See the source code [here](https://github.com/mixare/mixare/tree/master/src/org/mixare/data/convert) on how Mixare can retrieve Twitter or Wikipedia JSON formatted data using specialized Data Processor classes.